# Problem testing with Database in Play (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying to run a test using a local in memory database and to do so I need to

`import play.api.db.{Databases}`

I have added:

`libraryDependencies += jdbc`

to my build.sbt file as `jdbc` is where the `Databases` object lives.

I found through another StackOverflow question and https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/issues/280 that I need to disable the `play.api.db.DBModule` to successfully import `Databases`. So I have

`play.modules.disabled += "play.api.db.DBModule"`

in my applications.conf file. Have run `sbt update` and `activator update`. Still no dice.

Comment: Did you try `sbt clean` and then `sbt update`

Comment: Yes I have tried that. Thanks.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: Sorry that was ambiguous. No it's not working. I have already tried to `clean` and `update`.